# Mac: Everything quits unexpectedly

Tags: macos, osx-leopard

I have a friend with a Mac which runs OS/X 10.5 (Leopard).

He has minimal computer experience.

He says that EVERY application excluding Minecraft fails to open with an error message resembling "The application quit unexpectedly".

Does anybody else have an idea how to solve this?

Edit:

I extracted a bit more information out of him. He says he had a different (newer) OS, but he deleted a file which caused his computer to crash. He installed Leopard, which fixed his computer. I can't figure out whether the problem started directly after he installed Leopard, or some time after that. He always answers a different question from what I am asking.

Comment: There are several reason why your friend may get this error. These vary from a full disk (very easy to check), permission problems, font problems (shared a among many applications!) to a corrupted OS. Without additional information we can not help you with this. A good starting point would be to ask your friend just what he changed before the problems started.

Comment: I do not have a mac, so I can not test this myself, but please check out http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2216 (  Applications don't work after reinstalling Mac OS X )

Comment: So the problem may simply be that he is using an older version of Mac OS X than was originally installed?

Comment: Close. I suspect it is because his applications are configured for some tool-kits or frameworks which got changed when the OS got reinstalled. The correct solution might be to reinstall all his applications again, or to make and test a backup, do a clean full reinstallation of the OS and then reinstall the applications. (Compare it to a windows install where you install windows 7, add programs, mess up win7 and install vista without reinstalling any programs. Just keeping all old stuff in place and not using any installers.)

Comment: But applications which come with the OS should be automatically re-installed when the OS itself is re-installed, right? I'm confused as to how one would even go about re-installing EVERY application.

Comment: For the first question: try asking it to a person who owns a computer with OS/X :)    As for the second, when a computer is that messed up, you check if you have a backup off all your data and then do a full reinstallation. From what I am told the last is quite easy on a mac.

Comment: Like I said, this friend of mine is a little computer challenged. I doubt he has any more data than Minecraft. I'll talk to him about what you've said.